# Arrayformula - Autofill Duplicate in each row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have Table with conditional dropdown menus. Example:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F | Column G | Column H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Car | Gasoline |  | Tires | License | Gasoline |  | OK |
| Boy | Danny |  | Adam | Andrew | Danny |  | OK |
| Boy | Adam |  | Adam | Andrew | Danny |  | OK |
| Car | Adam |  | Tires | License | Gasoline |  | FALSE |
| Car | Gasoline |  | Tires | License | Gasoline |  | OK |

- Column A - Main Dropdown
- Column B - conditional-depends on Main (A)
- Columns D,E,F - Options for conditional dropdown (depends on Main (A)
- Column H - Verificator - This is what I need.

I am looking for ARRAYFORMULA that will Find out if Column B is OK (choosen from D,E or F) - for each row, and if not- then gets some kind of message-  like "FALSE".

so for each row separately - and it has to be arrayformula because rows are added via script and I don't want to copy formula to each row every time. and it has to check row by row so B1 - D1:F1, B2- D2:F2 ..  in reality I have this options from "R" to "HI" so if possible please do not compare value with D / E / F separately.

Also if there is some kind of workaround to not to have columns for conditional dropdown, it would be perfect.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, it will return OK if the value in column B is in Column D-F, same row? If not it will return false. In your sample from the post why is row 2 (Andrew) returning OK

Comment: You understand it well. I edit that. it was my mistake :)

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like this. It will try to match value in R to HI from that row (that's why I used INDEX, to narrow the search):

```
=BYROW(B:B,LAMBDA(each,IF(each="","",IFERROR(XMATCH(each,INDEX(R:HI,ROW(each))),FALSE))))
```

It will return the number of column or FALSE if it isn't found, you may add ">1" to return TRUE if found:

```
=BYROW(B:B,LAMBDA(each,IF(each="","",IFERROR(XMATCH(each,INDEX(R:HI,ROW(each)))>1,FALSE))))
```

Comment: Can you please use it in demo I created?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nfXvN5sRd_c8IPGquo0CR_kQ_i7EMhWKTZ7IBiOUbRQ/edit?usp=sharing
I put it to Formula 1 and 2  but it seems not working ... 
( I use semicolon except of colon - idk if google change it automatically )

Comment: There it is! `=BYROW(C7:C;LAMBDA(each;IF(each="";"";IFERROR(XMATCH(each;INDEX(E:G;ROW(each)))>=1;FALSE))))`